# Regular expressions in Fitnesse Tables

Tags: java, regex, fixtures, fitnesse

I am trying to process a string with a date in Fitnesse:

> "2016-06-09T15:20:03.336+01:00 @ Perspective editor; User: admin"

The date part of the string will change on every test run.

My understanding is that I can use =~/regex here/ in my results table i.e.

```
|name|Change String|Status|
|ui-comp/P1 Test Perspective.txt|=~/[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}T[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{3}\+01:00 @ Perspective editor; User: admin/|ADDED|
```

AFAIK the regex is good and should work, but my test still fails with:

> =~/[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}T[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{3}+01:00 @ Perspective editor; User: admin/ expected
>   2016-06-09T15:20:03.336+01:00 @ Perspective editor; User: admin actual

Any ideas what I am doing wrong here?  The java code simply fetches some table rows via selenium and puts them in a setFixture, like this:

```
@Override
public SetFixture getEventTable() throws Exception {
    return new SetFixture(getTableElement('EventTable').getRows('added'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you don't have any extra spaces at the beginning or the end of your actual value, should be easy to spot with the different shades of red in the result page, everything else seems to be fine.